# BufferedReader.readLine() method blocking flow

Tags: java, bufferedreader, processbuilder

I am hitting some commands through java code with the help of Process Builder.
Following is my code

```
Process poc = null;
List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
BufferedReader response = null;

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.directory(new File(commands.get(GlobalConstants.ADB_PATH_WINDOW)));
poc = pb.start();
```

And I am reading its output using BufferedReader:

```
response = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(poc.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
while ((line = response.readLine()) != null) 
{
    result.add(line);
    if (line.contains("daemon started successfully")) 
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

But Sometimes `line = response.readLine()` method goes in `infinite loop`.
I know what the cause is, but I am unable to resolve this by using `readLine()` function.
Can somebody help me with different reading logic.

Comment: Are you sure the `daemon started successfully` text appears on stdout and not stderr? You don't redirect stderr in your `ProcessBuilder`. Also, why use a `LinkedList`? Iterations of `List`s respect insertion order by contract, so an `ArrayList` is enough

Comment: Using LinkedList or ArrayList does not the correspond to this question. Yes, Infinite loop means it sleeps and wait for the end of the file. But it didn't recognize EOF, thats why it does not return its control to code. My question is: Is there any other method which can replace readLine() function?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the error is comming from another reason. 
Check if the EOF is really reached by:

```
try {
while (true) {
    result.add(response.readLine());
    if (line.contains("daemon started successfully")) 
    {
        return result;
    }
} } catch (EOFException e) {}
```

Comment: how would an empty catch statement help checking?

Comment: no more infinite loops? ofc you can add any console output there

Comment: I don't see how that would fix an endless loop either. Would you like to clarify? if there's an endless loop, how would catching EOFException help?

Comment: It just makes clear if EOF is reached or not. OP said his version sometimes goes into an infinite loop allthough the EOF is/should be reached. I thought about (line = response.readLine()) != null issues. catching the EOFE will now stop this loop

Comment: If there would've been an exception it would have stopped the loop anyway, so there's nothing this catch actually adds.